# Can I use the same list in the backing bean to display two different selectOneMenu's in two different dialogs?

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I have two different dialogs and both of them need to have a selectOneMenu so that the user can select a city. The same backing bean handles both of these dialogs. My question is: can I use the same list variable to display both of these selectOneMenus? For example

```
List<City> citiesList = dao.getCities() ...
```

and then the getter

```
public List<City> getCitiesList(){
    return citiesList;
}
```

can I use the same

```
#{myBean.citiesList}
```

in both dialogs?

Comment: I think you can use the same but it is dependent on the scope of managed bean. If the scope is session or application, the list data is identical for both.

Comment: Yes you can but you might have inconsistencies in future.

Comment: The bean is View Scoped.

Comment: So You can use same bean in scope. As it's just for view purpose

Comment: If City List never going to use and both `SelectoneMenu` need same List better use Cache for that type of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same `List<City> citiesList=dao.getCities()`... But you should use different variable for selected city. like

```
City selectedCityDialog1;
City selectedCityDialog2;
```